# How can I control the media player with service?

Tags: java, class, android-mediaplayer, seekbar

I am new to coding and at this point, I made a media player that starts and pauses the audio, has a working seekbar, duration, etc. Now I faced a big issue. The audio can't be played in the background and I found out that I can do this with service but this changes things. I read all kinds of topics on how to control the audio in service with seekbar and all kinds of stuff but nothing helped me. The main problem I face is having the seekbar to control the audio and a text to read the time. If there is someone to help me find a code for this it would be much appreciated.

[image]

The layout:

```
 <SeekBar
    android:id="@+id/seekBarMusic1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/_20sdp"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_12sdp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/_20sdp"
    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/_20sdp"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/cardView"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="10dp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/playerPositionMusic"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="00:00"
    android:textColor="@color/remain_black"
    android:textSize="25dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/_80sdp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/cardView"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/seekBarMusic1" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/text_time"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/_80sdp"
    android:text="15:00"
    android:textColor="@color/remain_black"
    android:textSize="25dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/cardView"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/seekBarMusic1" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/btPlayMusic"
    android:layout_width="80dp"
    android:layout_height="80dp"
    android:alpha="0.9"
    android:background="@drawable/play"
    android:theme="@style/Button.White"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/text_time"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/playerPositionMusic"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/seekBarMusic1"
    app:tint="@color/remain_black" />

 <ImageView
    android:visibility="gone"
    android:id="@+id/btPauseMusic"
    android:layout_width="80dp"
    android:layout_height="80dp"
    android:alpha="0.9"
    android:background="@drawable/pause"
    android:theme="@style/Button.White"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/text_time"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/playerPositionMusic"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/seekBarMusic1"
    app:tint="@color/remain_black" />
```

The code I used before:

```
public class m1 extends AppCompatActivity {

ImageView btPlay, btPause;
TextView playerPosition, playerDuration;
CircularSeekBar seekBar;

MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;
Handler handler = new Handler();
Runnable runnable;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_m1);

    findViewById(R.id.backm1).setOnClickListener(v -> onBackPressed());

    playerPosition = findViewById(R.id.playerPosition);
    playerDuration = findViewById(R.id.playerDuration);
    replay = findViewById(R.id.replay);
    forward = findViewById(R.id.forward);
    seekBar = findViewById(R.id.seekBar);
    btPause = findViewById(R.id.btPause);
    btPlay = findViewById(R.id.btPlay);

        mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw.ding_dong);

    runnable = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            seekBar.setProgress(mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition());

            handler.postDelayed(this,500);
        }
    };

    int duration = mediaPlayer.getDuration();

  String sDuration = convertFormat(duration);

  playerDuration.setText(sDuration);

  btPlay.setOnClickListener(v -> {

      mediaPlayer.start();

      btPlay.setVisibility(View.GONE);

      btPause.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

      seekBar.setMax(mediaPlayer.getDuration());

      handler.postDelayed(runnable, 0)

  });

  btPause.setOnClickListener(v -> {

      mediaPlayer.stop();

      btPause.setVisibility(View.GONE);

      btPlay.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);


      handler.removeCallbacks(runnable);

  });


  seekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new CircularSeekBar.OnCircularSeekBarChangeListener() {
      @Override
      public void onProgressChanged(CircularSeekBar circularSeekBar, float v, boolean b) {

          if (b) {

              mediaPlayer.seekTo((int) v);

          }
          playerPosition.setText(convertFormat(mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition()));
      }

      @Override
      public void onStopTrackingTouch(CircularSeekBar circularSeekBar) {

      }

      @Override
      public void onStartTrackingTouch(CircularSeekBar circularSeekBar) {

      }
  });

  mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(mp -> {
      btPause.setVisibility((View.GONE));

      btPlay.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

      mediaPlayer.seekTo(0);
  });

    }
}
@SuppressLint("DefaultLocale")
    private String convertFormat(int duration) {
        return String.format("%02d:%02d"
                ,TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(duration)
                ,TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(duration) -
                TimeUnit.MINUTES.toSeconds(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(duration)));
}
@Override
public void onPause()
{
    if(mediaPlayer != null && mediaPlayer.isPlaying())
    {
        mediaPlayer.stop();
    }
    super.onPause();
}

}
```

The code I am using now:

```
 btPause = findViewById(R.id.btPauseMusic);
    btPlay = findViewById(R.id.btPlayMusic);

    btPlay.setOnClickListener(v -> {

        startService(new Intent(this, BackgroundMusicService.class));

        btPlay.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        btPause.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    });

    btPause.setOnClickListener(v -> {

        stopService(new Intent(this, BackgroundMusicService.class));

        btPause.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        btPlay.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    });

}
```

And the service class:

```
public class BackgroundMusicService extends Service {

private MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;

@Nullable
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.ding_dong);
    mediaPlayer.start();
    return START_STICKY;
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();

    mediaPlayer.stop();
}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You are using different MediaPlayer in the Activity from the one in the backgroundService
you don't need to initialize another mediaPlayer in the activity you have to control the one in the backgroundService with Broadcast receivers like this for example to pause a the mediaPlayer in the backgroundService you do something like this

```
 private BroadcastReceiver pausePlayingAudio = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            pause();
            updateMetaData();
            buildNotification(PlaybackStatus.PAUSED);
            playbackStatus = PlaybackStatus.PAUSED ;

        }
    };
    private void register_pausePlayingAudio(){
        IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter(SongAdapter.ACTION_PAUSE) ;
        registerReceiver(pausePlayingAudio , intentFilter) ;
    }
```

and you call register_pausePlayingAudio() in onCreate() of the backGroundService

now say when a user clicks on a button in the activity and you want to pause you use something like this

```
sendBroadcast(new Intent(SongAdapter.ACTION_PAUSE));
```

I have and old project not finished doesn't have a seekBar but the seekBar implementation will be similar just instead of pause() you call seekTo() so you can check it

[the repo](https://github.com/khaled279/Rythemica-2.0)

Comment: For what do I need the  register_pausePlayingAudio() ?

Comment: You need to register the BroadcastReciever so that it starts listening to the intent and also you need to call unregisterReciever()  in the onDestory() to avoid memory leaks

Comment: If you don't register the receiver nothing would happen when you broadcast the pauseIntent

Comment: I have only one more question. For every music I have a card view, after clicked, every card has its own player activity. That's the way I wanted it to work. Now, I don't need any notification and the music has no album or things like that, is something simple like the service I initially showed. Can you help me modify that SongAdapter class to match my requirements? If you have any questions just ask me.

Comment: I'm assuming you mean you want to play the music in a different activity other than the one with the cards just make the onItemSelectedListner() move you to the next activity and pass the data you need to the other activity with the intent.putExtra() method, and from there bind the playing activity to the service and use the same way in the answer to control the media player in the service, and it's always q good Idea to have a notificationCard for any running service even if it has no controls at all and just says music is playing or something like just as an indication

Answer (score 1):

This article [Creating Media player service](https://www.sitepoint.com/a-step-by-step-guide-to-building-an-android-audio-player-app/) shows step by step on how you can implement a service to create a Mediaplayer application to run in the background.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, but the biggest problem I face right now is controlling the media with the seekbar and to have a text that reads the duration. I am going to show some more information in the question.

Comment: @jad-v-a don't post links to something as answers. post your actual answer as an answer, and add the link as 'additional info'

Comment: How it does work in light of the fact that the MEDIA_CONTENT_CONTROL permission is reserved and not allowed for third-party apps?